# Spring Integration SpEL issues with annotation

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have my fileMessageProvider() as

```
@InboundChannelAdapter( value = "files" , poller = @Poller(  fixedDelay = "${my.poller.interval}", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"  ))
 public Message<File> fileMessageProvider() {
    ...
 }
```

Gives NumberFormatException upon deployment

```
Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myPoller' defined in "../MyPoller.class": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{#my.poller.interval}"
```

Instead of SpEL If I use fixedDelay = "10000" , it works good.

My Spring integration version '4.0.0.RELEASE'

**Update:1**

I am using a mix of annotation and xml configuration

Batch.properties

```
my.poller.interval=20000
```

integration-context.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:Batch.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.org.reader" />

<int:transformer  input-channel="files" output-channel="requests">
    <bean class="com.org.reader.MyMessageToJobRequest">
        <property name="job" ref="addMessages"/>
    </bean>
</int:transformer>
```

Comment: Try using #{ <expression string> } insted {# <expression string>}

Comment: Tried fixedDelay = "#{my.poller.interval}"
gives similar exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "#{my.poller.interval}"

Comment: Change # to $. It should look like `${my.poller.interval}`. It works of course if you have `my` object which has `pooler` property which has `interval` property.

Comment: Can You post Your property file ? and the way you're reading it ?

Comment: Tried with fixedDelay = "${my.poller.interval}". This is the exception message in that case
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${my.poller.interval}"

Comment: I have updated the question with property file and reading of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have similar test-case on the matter and exactly since the raise of this feature:

```
    @Override
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "output",
            poller = @Poller(maxMessagesPerPoll = "${poller.maxMessagesPerPoll}", fixedDelay = "${poller.interval}"))
    @Publisher
    @Payload("#args[0].toLowerCase()")
    @Role("foo")
    public String handle(String payload) {
        return payload.toUpperCase();
    }
```

But yes: I have to confirm that it stops to work properly if we specify `<context:property-placeholder>` in the XML config instead of `@PropertySource` on the `@Configuration` class.

I can't recall the particular JIRA on the matter, but I remember that with the annotation and XML configuration mix, the first one has precedence and the environment must be configured in the `@Configuration` class.

For my sample it looks like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableIntegration
@PropertySource("classpath:org/springframework/integration/configuration/EnableIntegrationTests.properties")
@ImportResource("classpath:org/springframework/integration/configuration/EnableIntegrationTests-context.xml")
@EnableMessageHistory({"input", "publishedChannel", "annotationTestService*"})
public class ContextConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }   

}
```

**UPDATE**

From other side I found how to make it working from the Framework perspective.

So, it is a bug and I'm raising a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3853) on the matter.

Thank you for sharing your experience!

Comment: With @PropertySource my requirement is working good. Thank you for the support. I am glad that I could bring up this bug.